# Should it be 'from the My Portal' or 'from My Portal'?

Tags: grammaticality

I have a portal (a website serving as a guide or point of entry to the World Wide Web). It has a name (let's say, 'My Portal').

So, which of the two is correct? Or are both viable?

> Get it from the My Portal.

Or

> Get it from My Portal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a countable noun, then use an article in front of it just like you would any other countable noun.

> I got the kids out of the Porsche.
>   I created a Myspace account.
>   I ate at the Jack & Jill Restaurant down the street.

Let's assume that My Portal is a product, one that is countable and more than one person owns.

It would make perfect sense to say:

> I got home and checked my My Portal.
>   Your My Portal is broken. You should buy another one.
>   I need to look up that information at the My Portal at the coffee shop across the street.

Just because it sounds a bit odd at first use, that doesn't mean the syntax is wrong. If everybody *did* have one, it would quickly become commonplace and sound normal.

If it's a countable noun, then form your sentence just as you would from the noun *washing machine* (or any other common noun), simply replace the words.

> Get your clothes from the washing machine.
>   Get your books from the library.
>   Get your information from the My Portal.

---

But if it's a *unique* proper noun, then form your sentence as you would with that in mind.

> Get your pizza from Chicago.
>   Get your salmon from Alaska.
>   Get your information from My Portal.

Answer (score 0):

> Get it  from the 'My Portal'

sounds awkward, but it is grammatically correct.  "**My Portal**" is the title of a **product** and you are using a definite article to specify.  That being said, I wouldn't say it in normal speech.  I would say

> Get it from My Portal

Both are grammatically correct, but the latter would be more accepted in every day speech

That being said though, I could see the former become a habitual way of saying something in a company as part of its regular way of referring to things.  Corporate language can generate acceptability for those kinds of things.  Lord knows the number of acronyms I use at work.

Comment: Making sure I understand... a definite article could precede the name of a place, even if it's not used in everyday speech? So, for example, "She lives in the Japan" is grammatically correct?

Comment: "My Portal" is a product.  I will edit my answer, but you do say She lives in the Hague or She lives in the Netherlands.  There would be no question involved if the product name was just "portal."  You would say, "Put in the Portal."